# Why does my 160kb app background become 49 MB at run time?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-memory

I decided to investigate my app's memory usage and I looked at Android Studio's Memory Monitor and my memory usage was around 68 MB. It looks too high to me.

[image]

I opened memory allocator and started tracking from the beginning of the application. I saw that there is a 49 MB allocation of a `NonMovableArray`, which is a `Bitmap`.

[image]

I debugged the application and found out that it was the background I was using. The lines below are from `PhoneWindow.java` file, that's where Android assigns the background to the screen I believe. The background object had a size of **49 MB** and 2625x4669 resolution.

I have no overdraw in my app, and I have a single background that is applied to entire theme.

I have a background drawable in `drawable` folder in JPG format with 750x1,334 resolution.

**PhoneWindow.java**

```
if (mBackgroundResource != 0) {
    background = getContext().getDrawable(mBackgroundResource);
} else {
    background = mBackgroundDrawable;
}
```

I am testing this on a Motorola Nexus 6 device which has 560 density with  a resolution of 1440 x 2560.

There are two points I don't understand.

1. If the device has a resolution of 1440x2560, why would my background get converted to 2625x4669?
2. Even if this conversion is the best scenario for the app, how come a 160 KB file would end up being 49 MB?

If you guys can explain this to me that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If the device has a resolution of 1440x2560, why would my background get converted to 2625x4669?

You put the image in `res/drawable/`. This is not a good choice, as that is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`. Hence, Android is resampling your image, thinking that you were aiming for `-mdpi` devices (~160dpi), so the image is about the same physical size on the Nexus 6 (3.5x the density).

Whether `res/drawable-nodpi/` or `res/drawable-anydpi/` is the right choice depends a bit on your alternative versions of this resource, though [either will probably work](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/21/nodpi-anydpi-wtf.html).

> how come a 160 KB file would end up being 49 MB?

The image takes up 160KB **on disk**. The memory footprint is the decoded image. That will be the image resolution (post-resampling) times 4 bytes/pixel for `ARGB_8888` images. 2625x4669x4 ~= 49MB.

Comment: I already solved this problem first putting my drawable in 'drawable-nodpi` folder (after seeing an answer of you to another question), and then creating different drawables for different screen densities. I just wanted to understand what was the reason behind it, and you explained very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The default and highest quality configuration for a `Bitmap` is `ARGB_8888`, which will use 4 bytes per pixel. Since your image is being scaled to 2625*4669, that's:

```
2625*4669*4 bytes = 49024500 bytes
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the resolution differences, but the difference between the used memory and the size of the file is because an image in the **JPG** format (as many other formats) is compressed (see the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) for how). When you then load it into memory, it is no longer compressed, as it's used to draw every single pixel on the screen.